# Launching a second Linux program and exit current one from C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, linux, qt, boost-process

Is it possible from a C or C++ Linux program (say `/usr/bin/foo`), to programmatically launch another program (say `/usr/bin/bar`), and have `foo` exit normally and for `bar` to keep running?

`system(3)` isn't suitable as it blocks until the other program completes.  I'd like something that returns immediately.

The programs are both GUI programs, but I suspect that isn't relevant.

Is there anything in Qt or boost::process that can help?

Is there any common Linux wrapper program I could run through `system(3)` to achieve this?  I tried `xdg-open` but I don't think it's the right thing.

Basically I want the second program to "detach" from the first, and behave as if the user launched it via the system UI.  (On MacOS, for example, there is an `open` command, so it would be like `system("open /usr/bin/bar")`)

Comment: A combination of `fork()` and `execv()` is how it is usually done. Alternatively, you can `system()` it with `&` in the end to run in the background, but that's nasty.

Comment: Since you mention `boost::process` you might want to take a look at [`boost::process::spawn`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/process/spawn.html) or the class [`boost::process::child`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html) which allows you to set up and create a child process before [detaching](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/doc/html/boost/process/child.html#idm45349852765600-bb) it.

Comment: Since you mentioned Qt, there's [`QProcess::start`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#start) that does this.

Comment: @rustyx: Are we sure its ok for the parent process to exit while the process started with `QProcess::start` keeps running?

Comment: @rustyx: Maybe `QProcess::startDetached` looks like the right thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `Qt`, you can use `bool QProcess::startDetached(const QString &program, const QStringList &arguments, const QString &workingDirectory = QString(), qint64 *pid = nullptr)` as described here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html#startDetached

Here is a minimal example of how to use it :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QProcess>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    /*
     * starting netstat with args
     * in case the main event loop is exited
     * netstat will be parented to init ( pid 1 ) and continue running
     */
    QProcess::startDetached("/bin/netstat", QStringList() << "-pla" << "-ntuc");

    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The classic way is using Fork-Exec: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork%E2%80%93exec which is available in any Unix derived OS, including Linux. No need to add any library, framework, etc.

Comment: I ended up using `QProcess::startDetached`, but I'm sure under the hood its just doing fork-exec as you suggest.